# How to solve 'undefined reference to'

Tags: cmake, undefined-reference, itk

I got some of this error when I compile on Ubuntu 16.04.1,

```
Linking CXX executable ../lib/Slicer-4.7/cli-modules/abcd
    /path/to/SimpleITK/SimpleITK-build/SimpleITK-build/lib/libSimpleITKBasicFilters1-0.11.so.1: undefined reference to `itk::ImageToImageFilter<itk::Image<int, 2u>, itk::Image<int, 2u> >::PushFrontInput(itk::DataObject const*)'
```

Does this `undefined reference to` means SimpleITK is not linked?
Following is my Cmakelist:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.8)

#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
set(MODULE_NAME "abcd")

#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
set(MODULE_HOMEPAGE "${_EXT_HOMEPAGE}")
set(MODULE_CATEGORY "${_EXT_CATEGORY}")
set(MODULE_CONTRIBUTORS "abc")
set(MODULE_DESCRIPTION "abc" )
set(MODULE_ACKNOWLEDGEMENTS "${_EXT_ACKNOWLEDGEMENTS}")
set(MODULE_LICENSE_SHORT_DESCRIPTION "${MODULE_LICENSE_SHORT_DESCRIPTION}")
set(MODULE_MAJOR_VERSION "${_EXT_MAJOR_VERSION}")
set(MODULE_MINOR_VERSION "${_EXT_MINOR_VERSION}")
set(MODULE_PATCH_VERSION "${_EXT_PATCH_VERSION}")

# Configure XML description
configure_file(
  ${MODULE_NAME}.xml.in
  ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/${MODULE_NAME}.xml
  @ONLY
  )

#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
set(MODULE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES
  )

set(MODULE_SRCS
  )

set(MODULE_TARGET_LIBRARIES
  ${ITK_LIBRARIES} ${SimpleITK_LIBRARIES}
  )

#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
SEMMacroBuildCLI(
  NAME ${MODULE_NAME}
  TARGET_LIBRARIES ${MODULE_TARGET_LIBRARIES}
  INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES ${MODULE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES}
  ADDITIONAL_SRCS ${MODULE_SRCS}
  )

#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
if(BUILD_TESTING)
  add_subdirectory(Testing)
endif()
```

But as you can see, I do have link target library 
SimpleITK, and ITK, and that slicer module works fine in slicer 4.4 version but after slicer updates to 4.7, it does not work.
Does anyone know how to fix that, or give me some clue? Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There may be a problem with the intra-dependencies in SimpleITK with the version Slicer is using
Change:

```
set(MODULE_TARGET_LIBRARIES
  ${ITK_LIBRARIES} ${SimpleITK_LIBRARIES}
  )
```

to:

```
set(MODULE_TARGET_LIBRARIES
  ${SimpleITK_LIBRARIES} ${SimpleITK_LIBRARIES} ${ITK_LIBRARIES} 
  )
```

I believe the follow patch in SimpleITK will addressed the problem:
https://github.com/SimpleITK/SimpleITK/commit/6fc22492ca1fd3ebb493160b7968c37a0a6f1986

Comment: This seems not working, do you have any other idea? Thanks a lot

Comment: Another thing to try is to turn of SimpleITK shared libraries: https://github.com/Slicer/Slicer/blob/master/SuperBuild/External_SimpleITK.cmake#L68 If that doesn't work then "-DSITK_EXPLICIT_INSTANTIATION:BOOL=0" would be the last thing to try.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem seems to be with internal inconsistency of SimpleITK. Namely, some part of libSimpleITKBasicFilters1-0.11.so.1 expects [PushFrontInput](https://itk.org/Doxygen/html/classitk_1_1ImageToImageFilter.html#a1206d74aee577e235f9bb11cdf1dc34e) to be defined elsewhere, when it probably should have been exported from (or at least defined in) that library.

Edit: Slicer 4.7 is the current development version, and is hence unstable. Try 4.6.2 which is the latest stable release.